# Meaning of who as an adverb

Tags: meaning

Is the usage of who correct in the following sentence

> The account was confirmed by an administration official **who** also on condition of anonymity.

Is it a contraction of **who also spoke on** condition of anonymity?

[Link](https://www.thehindu.com/news/international/trump-took-shelter-in-white-house-bunker-as-protests-raged/article31719465.ece?homepage=true)

Comment: I think the sentence is incomplete  or ungrammatical.

Comment: The previous sentence mentions someone who spoke on condition of anonymity. This sentence was intended to say "who also spoke on condition of anonymity." No such contraction is possible, so it's a typographical or proofreading error.